# How can I find similar rows in a table?

Tags: r

I have an issue with survey data where there are fake responses that come from the same IP that are very similar - basically people clicking through and making the same answers most of the time.  However, I do have some genuine responses from the same IP, so I can't just filter on that.

What I'm hoping to do is to find "similar" rows in a manner akin to finding duplicate rows, but where the restraints are relaxed and the outcome is a similarity score (ie what percent of values in row 1 match in row 2).  I haven't been able to find a package for this.

```
require(tidyverse)
require(janitor)
x <- structure(list(group = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
                              "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c"), 
val1 = c(2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1), 
val2 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1), 
val3 = c(4, 3, 5, 1, 1, 5, 3, 5, 5, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4), 
val4 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), val5 = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2), 
val6 = c(2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2)), 
row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

x %>% get_dupes()

#No variable names specified - using all columns.

# A tibble: 2 x 8
#  group  val1  val2  val3  val4  val5  val6 dupe_count
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl>      <int>
#1 a         1     3     5     1     1     1          2
#2 a         1     3     5     1     1     1          2


x %>% get_dupes(val1, val2, val4, val5, val6)

# # A tibble: 14 x 8
# val1  val2  val4  val5  val6 dupe_count group  val3
# <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl>      <int> <chr> <dbl>
#   1     1     1     1     2     2          3 a         3
# 2     1     1     1     2     2          3 c         1
# 3     1     1     1     2     2          3 c         4
# 4     1     2     1     2     2          2 a         1
# 5     1     2     1     2     2          2 b         5
# 6     1     3     1     1     1          3 a         5
# 7     1     3     1     1     1          3 a         5
# 8     1     3     1     1     1          3 b         4
# 9     1     3     1     2     2          2 a         4
# 10     1     3     1     2     2          2 c         3
# 11     2     1     1     1     2          2 a         4
# 12     2     1     1     1     2          2 b         2
# 13     2     3     1     1     1          2 b         3
# 14     2     3     1     1     1          2 c         3
```

Note that there are only 2 actual duplicates, but its mostly because of val3.  If we remove it from the duplicates check, there are 14.

What I'd like to find out is that for these 14 rows, they have `ncol(x)-1` similarities, or 1 dissimilarity.  I don't care where it is however, so it needs to be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

This is an approach based essentially on a double loop comparing rows. Essentially, you need to compare each of the `n` rows to the `n-1` other rows and compute the row's similarity. The function below does exactly that.

If you are thinking about more general ways to cope with duplication you could check out the `RecordLinkage` package, which would let you compute more general similarity scores between fields and play with some unsupervised classification algorithms for determining duplication.

However, here is a functional approach:

```r
require(tidyverse)
require(janitor)

x <- structure(list(group = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
                              "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c"), 
                    val1 = c(2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1), 
                    val2 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1), 
                    val3 = c(4, 3, 5, 1, 1, 5, 3, 5, 5, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4), 
                    val4 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), val5 = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2), 
                    val6 = c(2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2)), 
               row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

x %>% get_dupes()
#> No variable names specified - using all columns.
#> # A tibble: 2 x 8
#>   group  val1  val2  val3  val4  val5  val6 dupe_count
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl>      <int>
#> 1 a         1     3     5     1     1     1          2
#> 2 a         1     3     5     1     1     1          2

# A helper function for comparing rows and returning the number of non-matches
row_comp <- function(row1, row2) {
  sum(row1 != row2)
}

# The function for comparing all rows. You can set the 
# number of non-matches you'll tolerate 
get_n_dupes <- function(x, unmatch.tol = 1) {
  n <- nrow(x)
  dist.mat <- vector(length = n)
  for (i in seq_len(n)){
    dist.mat[i] <- any(apply(x[-i,], 1, 
                             function(row){row_comp(row, x[i,])}) <= unmatch.tol)
  }
  x[dist.mat,]
}

# By default this returns values that are a match bar-one
get_n_dupes(x)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 7
#>   group  val1  val2  val3  val4  val5  val6
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 a         1     3     5     1     1     1
#> 2 a         1     3     5     1     1     1
#> 3 b         2     3     3     1     1     1
#> 4 c         1     1     1     1     2     2
#> 5 c         2     3     3     1     1     1
#> 6 c         1     1     4     1     2     2

# If you up it to two potential non-matches nearly all the rows find a match
x %>% get_n_dupes(unmatch.tol = 2)
#> # A tibble: 19 x 7
#>    group  val1  val2  val3  val4  val5  val6
#>    <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 a         2     1     4     1     1     2
#>  2 a         1     1     3     1     2     2
#>  3 a         1     1     5     1     2     1
#>  4 a         1     2     1     1     2     2
#>  5 a         2     1     1     1     1     1
#>  6 a         2     2     5     1     1     2
#>  7 a         2     2     3     1     1     1
#>  8 a         1     3     5     1     1     1
#>  9 a         1     3     5     1     1     1
#> 10 a         1     3     4     1     2     2
#> 11 b         2     1     2     1     1     2
#> 12 b         2     1     3     1     2     2
#> 13 b         1     3     4     1     1     1
#> 14 b         1     2     5     1     2     2
#> 15 b         2     3     3     1     1     1
#> 16 c         1     3     3     1     2     2
#> 17 c         1     1     1     1     2     2
#> 18 c         2     3     3     1     1     1
#> 19 c         1     1     4     1     2     2
```